# Java: How to make a flowlayout arranges components top to bottom?

Tags: java, awt, flowlayout

Is there a way to make a FlowLayout arranges components in a top to bottom flow centered horizontally rather than a left to right one?

Comment: under what library? SWT?

Comment: I only thought there was one Flowlayout, but anyway `java.awt.FlowLayout;`

Comment: Use BoxLayout instead.